# Why __str__ function of parent class is called when using print on child

Tags: python, function, inheritance

`Sub` is inheriting from `Super` which implements `__str__` function. Why is the `__str__` function called when using `print` on a `Sub` instance ?

```
class Super:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "My name is " + self.name + "."


class Sub(Super):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Super.__init__(self, name)


obj = Sub("Andy")

print(obj)
```

Comment: Please check the documentation for [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__). When `print` is used on the obj, `__str__` is called to get the string representation of the object.

Comment: `Sub` inherits all attributes of `Super` that it doesn't define itself.  So it inherits `__str__`.  That's the whole point of inheritance.

Comment: Are you asking **why** `print` calls `__str__`, or **how** it ends up calling `Super.__str__` when there is no `Sub.__str__`? I think you have the answer in one of the existing comments either way, but the question is unclear.

Comment: Yes why it calls the __str__ if we pass obj inside the print function

Comment: @TomKarzes But `__str__(self)` means that it is a private method because of the leading underscore. But it is inherited by Sub. Why?

Comment: @slawalata That's just a convention.  Python doesn't treat names differently just because they begin with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two notions: **inheritance** and `__str__` function.

When you use `print` on a class instance, it will check for a `__str__` function in your class. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__).

Try this example:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __str__(self):
        return "My string"

myClassInstance = MyClass()

print(myClassInstance)  # My string
```

In your case, `Sub` [inherits](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) from `Super` meaning that all functions of the class `Super` are present in `Sub` if you don't redefine them.

This example will work the same as the previous one:

```py
class MyParentClass:

    def __str__(self):
        return "My string"


class MyChildClass(MyParentClass):
    pass


myChildClass = MyChildClass()

print(myChildClass)  # My string
```

Lastly, in your example, you defined an attribute `name` to your `Super` class. Because `Sub` constructor is calling `Super` constructor, you also have a `name` attribute in your `Sub` class. So `__str__` can find it and build your string as wanted.